# What sort of regex is this?

Tags: ios, regex, nsregularexpression

I just found someone using a regex like this:

```
NSString *pattern = @"i[\\p{Alphabetic}&&\\p{Uppercase}][\\p{Alphabetic}]+";
[NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:pattern options:0 error:NULL];
// Source: http://www.objc.io/issue-5/getting-to-know-textkit.html
// Tested. It actually works.
```

The regular expression looks pretty cool and readable (supposedly more compatible with Unicode). Where can I find more info on this kind of regex? Is it a Cocoa-only kind of thing?

**EDIT**: I found a comprehensive answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2062521/regex-unicode-properties-reference-and-examples).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess (might be totally wrong), that this kind of regularExpression is used with *UNICODE PROPERTY NAME* expression, as you already mentioned. You can use it with the *NSRegularExpression* class.

References can be found [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSRegularExpression_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009708-CH1-SW48) from the apple developer page.
And [secondly](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr18/) from the unicode.org page.

Hope this helps.

Comment: If you might be totally wrong, you probably should check before answering!

Comment: I did, so I *risked* to add an answer, but mentioned it.

Comment: The Unicode TR18 page is not intended for people who uses regex engine, I think it is meant for people developing an engine yourself, or for people who want to know what a Unicode regex engine should support. For iOS, it uses ICU regex, so this is a much better documentation for people who use regex engine: http://userguide.icu-project.org/strings/regexp