# Regex to match anything but an alphanumeric character or a hyphen

Tags: regex, coldfusion, pcre

I am trying to allow users to register a username that contains only alphabet letters (of any language), numbers, or hyphens in it. I'm trying to check if a username breaks this rule.

So far this is working to find out if a username does **not** contain only alphanumeric characters:

```
REFindNoCase('^[[:alnum:]]', ARGUMENTS.Username)
```

Which is fine because if I get back a found result then I know its an invalid username format with special characters in it. But I also want to allow hyphens through. How could I express in regex like (pseudo-code follows):

```
REFindNoCase('^[[:alnum:]\-]', ARGUMENTS.Username)
```

I can only use Perl compatible Regex because I am using ColdFusion which uses that standard mostly.

Comment: PCRE isn't Perl. Fixed tags.

Comment: @ikegami ColdFusion supports regular expressions that are Perl compliant only

Comment: That's impossible. It probably uses the "Perl Compatible Regular Expressions" (PCRE) engine which is different than Perl's.

Comment: @ikegami: correct. CF uses Apache ORO, which is a (very old and decrepit) PCRE implementation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, you're wrong about `REFindNoCase('^[[:alnum:]]', ARGUMENTS.Username)` being fine. It checks if the first character is alphnumeric.

```
$ for q in Abcdef Abc123 Abc-123 Abc/123 ; do
   if echo "$q" | grep -qP '^[[:alnum:]]'
   then echo "$q: match"
   else echo "$q: no match"
   fi
done
Abcdef: match
Abc123: match
Abc-123: match
Abc/123: match
```

(`grep -P` uses PCRE too.)

To look for character that is not an `alnum` character, you'd use

```
[^[:alnum:]]
```

As seen here:

```
$ for q in Abcdef Abc123 Abc-123 Abc/123 ; do
   if echo "$q" | grep -qP '[^[:alnum:]]'
   then echo "$q: match"
   else echo "$q: no match"
   fi
done
Abcdef: no match
Abc123: no match
Abc-123: match
Abc/123: match
```

To look for character that are neither an `alnum` character nor "-", you'd use

```
[^[:alnum:]-]
```

As seen here:

```
$ for q in Abcdef Abc123 Abc-123 Abc/123 ; do
   if echo "$q" | grep -qP '[^[:alnum:]-]'
   then echo "$q: match"
   else echo "$q: no match"
   fi
done
Abcdef: no match
Abc123: no match
Abc-123: no match
Abc/123: match
```

By the way, `REFind` would work just as a well as `REFindNoCase` since `alnum` includes both uppercase and lowercase letters, so might as well use `REFind`.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I just solved it using after much trial and error: `REFind('[^[:alnum:]-]', ARGUMENTS.Username)`. I have no idea why it works, but the only difference is that the negation `^` is inside the first opening square bracket

Comment: That's the opposite of what you asked. That looks if the string contains a character that's neither an "alnum" nor a "-".

Comment: How do you mean? I want it to match where a string does not contain alphanumeric characters or a hyphen. Which would then in turn flag to me that the username contains special characters like `<>%$£` etc

Comment: Right, which is the opposite of what you asked.

Comment: Are there any other hyphens/dashes I need to include? There is a Unicode pattern of `{Pd}` which matches all sorts of dashes. Do you know of any equivalent I could use?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "need to include".

Comment: I mean I want it not to match the minus character as well which I guess is different to a hyphen. I suppose an em-dash and en-dash would also also be allowed.. so it shouldn't match on those either. Do I have to add all these manually like the hyphen character?

Comment: If you want to look for those specific chars, then yeah, you're going to have to add them. It will only look for the characters you specify

Answer (score 0):

Update: I looked at this question [RegEx: \w - "_" + "-" in UTF-8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2062169/regex-w-in-utf-8)

Final solution after trial and error (the negation had to be inside the opening bracket):

`REFind('[^[:alnum:]-]', ARGUMENTS.Username)`